# h:selectBooleanCheckbox enable and disable based on some condition

Tags: jsf, selectbooleancheckbox

I am a new bee to JSF.
I am trying to enable disable check box based on some condition.

Below is the code I tried with Google help but it's not working.

```
<c:if test="#{ml.dn.y == null}">    
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="ge" value="#{ml.dn.NonCInd}" />
    <h:outputText value="Generate"  style="font-weight: bold;"/> 
</c:if>
```

Comment: Use the rendered attribute instead such as `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox rendered="#{empty ml.dn.y}"/>`.

Comment: Try choosing search keywords more carefully. In (web/UI) development terms "enable and disable" is very, very different from "show and hide".

Comment: @Tiny When i try using Rendered i am not seeing the box, I need to disable the check box rather then hiding it.

Comment: `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{empty ml.dn.y}"/>`.

Comment: Thank you Tiny, I can i check two conitions?  like,   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{empty ml.dn.y} && #{empty ml.dd.s}"/>  when i tried doing this i got null source exception

Comment: Yes you can but this way : `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{empty ml.dn.y and empty ml.dd.s}"/>`.

Comment: That exception `NullPointerException` should have been thrown somewhere else - maybe in an associated backing bean which cannot reasonably be answered without looking into the associated portion that causes the exception to be thrown. EL itself cannot generate a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Sorry to say it is not disabling instead it is showing me a check box with tick mark, this is going to be last question to be asked Tiny...help me out....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69255/discussion-between-tom-and-tiny).